# State doesn't update inside setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, react-hooks

I'm making a simple progress bar and I've noticed strange behaviour of hook state when I'm using setInterval. Here is my sample code:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Example = ({title}) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [countInterval, setCountInterval] = useState(0)
  
  let intervalID
 
  const handleCount = () => {
    setCount(count + 1)
    console.log(count)
  }  
    
  const progress = () => {
    intervalID = setInterval(() => {
  setCountInterval(countInterval => countInterval + 1)
  console.log(countInterval)
  if(countInterval > 100) { // this is never reached
      setCountInterval(0)
      clearInterval(intervalID)
  }
 },100)
  }
  
  const stopInterval = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalID)
  }
    
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{title}</p>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <p>setInterval count { countInterval } times</p>
      <button onClick={handleCount}>
        Click me
      </button>
      <button onClick={progress}>
        Run interval
      </button>
      <button onClick={stopInterval}>
        Stop interval
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example title="Example using simple hook:" />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

If I set state by `handleCount` everything is happen as expected, but when I'm running `progress` function, **inside** setInterval `countInterval` value **doesn't change** at all. Regardless of it, `countInterval` **has changed in the state.**

To get this around I'm using variable inside `progress` function, like this:

```
  const progress = () => {
    let internalValue = 0
    intervalID = setInterval(() => {
        setCountInterval(internalValue)
        internalValue++
        if(internalValue > 100) {
      setCountInterval(0)
      clearInterval(intervalID)
        }
    },100)
  }
```

And that works fine, but I'm still wondering if there is a better approach and what I'm doing wrong in the first case.

The second problem is that I can't clear interval outside a `progress` function and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here or I miss something? Thanks in advance for any help and advices.

Comment: I think you should be using an [effect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for something like this.

Comment: Why not just `setCountInterval(countInterval => countInterval > 100 ? 0 : countInterval + 1)` ?

Comment: @JonasWilms This is pretty smart, but I need to clearInterval somehow as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problems are caused by your timer references being lost on re-renders, and the `setInterval` call-back referencing out-of-date versions of `setCountInterval`.

To get it fully working, I would suggest adding a state variable to track whether it is started or not and a `useEffect` to handle the setting and clearing of `setInterval`.

```
const Example = ({ title }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [countInterval, setCountInterval] = useState(0);
  const [started, setStarted] = useState(false);

  const handleCount = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    console.log(count);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let intervalID;
    if (started) {
      intervalID = setInterval(() => {
        setCountInterval(countInterval => countInterval + 1);
        console.log(countInterval);
        if (countInterval > 100) {
          setCountInterval(0);
          setStarted(false);
        }
      }, 100);
    } else {
      clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(intervalID);
  }, [started, countInterval]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{title}</p>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <p>setInterval count {countInterval} times</p>
      <button onClick={handleCount}>Click me</button>
      <button onClick={() => setStarted(true)}>Run interval</button>
      <button onClick={() => setStarted(false)}>Stop interval</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Working sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-leaf-h03mi

Comment: Thank you. This is what I expected.

Answer (score 2):

`countInterval` is a local variable, that contains a primitive value. By the nature of JavaScript, there is no way for `setState` to mutate that variable in any way. Instead, it reexecutes the whole `Example` function, and then `useState` will return the new updated value. That's why you can't access the updated state, until the component rerenders.

Your problem can trivially be solved by moving the condition into the state update callback:

```
 setCountInterval(countInterval => countInterval > 100 ? 0 : countInterval + 1)
```

---

Because of the rerendering, you can't use local variables, so `intervalId` will be recreated at every rerender (and it's value gets lost). Use `useRef` to use values across rerenders.

```
  const interval = useRef(undefined);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function stop() { 
    if(!interval.current) return;
    clearInterval(interval.current);
    interval.current = null;
  }

  function start() {
    if(!interval.current) interval.current = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(count => count > 100 ? 0 : count + 1);
    });
 }

 useEffect(() => {
   if(count >= 100) stop();
 }, [count]);
```

Comment: If this gets unmounted when it's running it'll cause a memory leak because setInterval won't get cleaned up